# client.on('messageUpdate' ....) not working properly?

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to log when a user edits a message.
Its not really working....

Here is my code:

```
client.on('messageUpdate', (oldMessage, newMessage) => {
    logMessageEdit(oldMessage, newMessage);
});

function logMessageEdit(oldMessage, newMessage) {

    if (!newMessage.guild.channels.find('name', "logs")) return;

    logChannel = newMessage.guild.channels.find('name', "logs");

    let logEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setAuthor(newMessage.author.tag, newMessage.author.avatarURL)
        .setDescription(` | Meddelande redigerat i ${oldMessage.channel}.`)
        .addField("Innan", "test" + oldMessage.content)
        .addField("Efter", "test" + newMessage.content)
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter(newMessage.id)
        .setColor(greenColor);

    logChannel.send(logEmbed)
}
```

[And here is what it results in:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6N0Ds.png)

Answer (score 2):

not too familiar with the `client.on('messageUpdate')` method but the bot is logging its own message sends, not just your messages. try updating your `client.on('messageUpdate')` method

```js
client.on('messageUpdate', (oldMessage, newMessage) => {
    if(newMessage.author.id === client.user.id) return;
    logMessageEdit(oldMessage, newMessage);
});
```

if this doesn't work check for other calls of logMessageEdit such as in the `client.on('message')` event